# Why bitcoind/bitcoin-qt is imposing transaction fee?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, bitcoin-core, transaction-fees

bitcoind is imposing a transaction fee of 0.0001 BTC forcefully even though I have set "transaction fee" to 0. Is it possible to transfer BTC to an address without paying a fee? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to Bitcoin version 0.9 or later which removes the minimum relay fee. Just be warned -- the lower the fee you set, the longer it can take for your transaction to be confirmed. Zero-fee transactions can take days.

Comment: I've had 0 fee transactions confirmed in minutes. dont believe the hype.

Comment: @jaybny I didn't say they can't take minutes, I said they can take days.

Comment: I've never had to wait over 12 hours ever. used many wallets over many years.

Comment: Did you modify the code to set the transaction fee to zero? 0.9 hasn't been out for long and previous versions don't let you force a zero fee.

Comment: Thanks David, I have upgraded to 0.9 but it is still including fee, can you please tell me what's the problem ?

Comment: @user14632 It must be a very unusual transaction then. Perhaps it's gathering from a large number of small outputs? Perhaps it's transferring coins that were recently transferred?

Comment: No that's not the case, it is saying, "The total exceeds your balance when 0.0001BTC transaction fee is included